# crm outlook report cannot have a default filter

Tags: dynamics-crm

Crm 2013 on premise - I have a report that works fine from the browser, but when I try to run it from the outlook client, the report viewer says "This report cannot have a default filter."
On the web client, if I select the report and click 'Edit default filter', I get the same message.

How do I start to diagnose the issue with the outlook client?

Answer (score 0):

You will get this message when the report defines user input parameters in the SSRS report definition. To get past this message, you need to update the RDL report file to remove all parameters which accept user input.

Comment: Won't this affect the report running in the context of the browser?

Comment: The engine Outlook and the browser use are exactly the same. If you want to be sure, you can create a copy of the problem report and make the adjustments. Then test the copy to see if it gives you the behavior you want.

Comment: The report does have 3 dropdowns that are used to filter the data. If I remove report parameters from the rdl, those dropdowns would go away, right? We just moved this report from 2011 to 2013, and it worked in 2011.

Comment: @user1202839 - Correct. If you have user parameters in the RDL file, you cannot set default CRM filters.